# Foreign registered car in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, spain, car

I am considering buying a Spanish registered car in the UK and driving it to Spain where it will be registerd in my name and left there permanently

If the car is close to the 6 month limit from the time it was brought over here by the previous owner, am I limited to that period to get it out of the country? Alternatively, if I bought the car and drove it in UK having already registered it in Spain, would I be breaking the law?

Comment: Are you yourself a UK resident?

Comment: I wonder how you could go about selling a car, and thus changing the owner's details on its vehicle registration card, when abroad. Isn't this usually done with the DVLA-equivalent in the registration country of the car?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.